# Function keys with external keyboard

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

When using an external keyboard, how can use a function key as a function key (e.g. F10) instead of Mac custom control button (e.g. mute)?  The built-in keyboard contains an `fn` button, but I cannot find it in the external one.

Comment: When you say external, do you mean 3rd party? I'm confused because the recent Apple keyboards, even the small ones, come with a Fn key.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The only way is to disable system-wide (that includes the notebook's keyboard) the custom control keys, and tell OS X that you just want to use it as normal F1-F12/F16 keys.

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard. Check the box that says "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys"

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Preferences in MacOS Catalina on a MacBook with a Touch Bar]

If you are using a Mac keyboard, there should be a Fn key. On the latest Mac wired slim aluminium keyboard, it is around the home, page up, page down area. On the wireless slim keyboard, it is to the bottom left.

Comment: When taking a screenshot of a single window in OS X, pressing command shift 4 space will allow you to capture the single window with it's drop shadow, without any other apps in the background.

Comment: @joshhunt nice screenshot :)

Comment: I am happy to report that you can safely enable this on the new 2016 macbook pros, and it works just fine for an external keyboard and leaves the touchbar intact!

Comment: On my mac it doesn't show the option "Use all F1, F2, ect. keys as standard...."

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work on a Cherry KC 6000 Slim for Mac.

Comment: This doesn't work for me...I already had that setting enabled and expected it to work as you have described, but it does so on my MacBook Pro's keyboard only. The external keyboard is still mapped in the default way, which is **extremely** annoying.

Answer (score 30):

Silly me.  The `fn` button is below `F13`.

Answer (score 18):

You can do that with [Karabiner-Elements](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements):

It allows you to configure the Fn keys per device. In this case, I set it to use the default keys when on the external keyboard:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that totally worked for me using a windows keyboard on the mac. Not only i now can use the function keys for media controls as default osx does, but i also remapped all special keys like CTRL/ALT/WINDOWS key to match the layout of a mac keyboard. Great! Note: If you also use a "windows" mouse and need different scrolling directions for the mouse and your trackpad, check out "Scroll Reverser"

Comment: I use Spark and it helped me to remap some shortcuts in my Windows PC Keyboard to control some basic functions like the volume commands. A Con, the app was not maintained in a long period of time. Latest version 3.1b2 (470) can be found at https://www.shadowlab.org/

Answer (score 8):

If you're using an external keyboard for a mac, check the external keyboard for a f-key lock button. On my logitech it is on the escape key.

*(I just spent half an hour figuring it out!)*

Comment: Thank you! I was struggling with this. Using Logitech MX Keys for Mac.

Comment: Good one! For the Microsoft Designer Keyboard it is even more hidden: fn + caps lock locks and unlocks the function keys.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly for me Scroll lock (F14) worked as brightness down and Pause Break (F15) as brightness up on a USB PC keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to Superuser, your answer doesn't sound like a good answer, you have not shown enough concern to compose it properly. Just  refer this link, https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you could try something like [this](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20080915065201592) utility.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Windows 7 under Boot Camp you can change in the Boot Camp control panel in your windows session.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had to go to *Keyboard* > *Keyboard Shortcuts* > *Function Keys* and enable "*Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys*"

My system: M2 Macbook Pro, 2022
MacOS: **Sonoma 14.1**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Corsair K95 RGB USB keyboard, I too was figuring out how to use the brightness control on my Mac and then when I used the F14 and F15 keys, it all surprisingly worked out.

Answer (score 0):

See if your keyboard manufacturer allows for this in their software. I installed Logi+ Options for my Logitech K380 and it allowed me to switch.

[Logitech Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK2K0.png)